# Work with pandas and openpyxl to generate xlsx broken from pandas 1.2.3 to 1.5.3

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I'm working with pandas (1.5.3) and openpyxl (3.0.7) on python 3.8, I've made a script to generate xlsx (from a template with color, text, formatting ...) from csv and json, some function can resize columns or add colors on condition. I was using pandas 1.2.3 and when I updated pandas to 1.5.3 it was impossible to make a basic to_excel with some edit (resize, color ...). Actually I can make an excel from a csv or json (.to_excel / sheet[coord] = myValue) this works fine, but if I want to do both operations (that was working with pandas 1.2.3) this doesn't work. I can actually (pandas 1.5.3) make one of those operations but not both, please help, I've tried many solutions / different synthax but none can fix my problem.
I write you down this post some example of function that I used.

basic dataframe to excel :

```
data = 'some .csv'
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(outfilename, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay', engine='openpyxl')
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(outfilename)
writer.workbook = book
data.to_excel(self.writer, sheet_name, startrow=start_row, startcol=start_column, header=header, index=index)
```

if I want to edit width I use the following code :

```
def autoResize(self, sheet_name, outfilename):
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(outfilename)
        sheet = book[sheet_name]

        for col in sheet.columns:
            column = col[0].column_letter # Get the column name
            max_length = 0

            ## get size of the title ##
            for cell in col:
                if max_length < len(str(cell.value)):
                    max_length = len(str(cell.value))

            adjusted_width = (max_length+2)*1.2
            sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width

        book.save(outfilename)

        return 0
```

Comment: If you're using a template, don't read using Pandas.

Comment: @CharlieClark i need to use pandas beacause I load big dataframe in some excel sheet and after I need to resize columns and/or add some data from json in some cell or color etc, what is you"r solution ?

Comment: There's still no need to use Pandas to read the workbook.

Comment: @CharlieClark so can u give me you'r solution ? Because I have made this post to get some response but you just say me that there's no need pandas but without a solution so ...

Comment: If you read the documentation you'll know what to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your proposed solutions, which move this post forward.